# image cropped as a triangle on webpage

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

This is a real css-challenge, I don't think this is possible:

I've made some white `css` triangles. and when you hover on a triangle, the white triangle should change in a photo also cropped like a triangle. I've made a jsfiddle for it:

[fiddleLink](http://jsfiddle.net/eaNEE/35/)

Any help appreciated

Comment: tough one. but you can fake it by inverting the transparency and treating it like a clipping area: jsfiddle.net/b4tGd/1

Comment: Almost, Dom Day. But my background of the body is a background image. So you can see the clipping area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use svg to achieve this effect: http://jsfiddle.net/xTd6Y/4/

```
<div id="image-wrapper">
    <svg id="svg-1" class="clip-svg">
        <rect class='svg-background' width="300" height="300" fill="#ffffff" />
        <image id="img-1" class='svg-image' width="300" height="300" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" />
    </svg>
    <svg id="svg-2" class="clip-svg">
        <rect class='svg-background' width="300" height="300" fill="#ffffff" />
        <image id="img-2" class='svg-image' width="300" height="300" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/300/301" />
    </svg>
    <svg id="svg-3" class="clip-svg">
        <rect class='svg-background' width="300" height="300" fill="#ffffff" />
        <image id="img-3" class='svg-image' width="300" height="300" xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/300/302" />
    </svg>
</div>
<svg id="svg-defs">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip-triangle">
            <polygon points="0, 200 100, 0 200, 200"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

css

```
body {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
#image-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.svg-background, .svg-image {
    clip-path: url(#clip-triangle);
}
.svg-image {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clip-svg .svg-image:hover {
    visibility: inherit;
}

/* size and positioning */
 svg.clip-svg {
    position: absolute;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}
#svg-1 {
    top: 110px;
    left: 50px;
}
#svg-2 {
    top: 40px;
    left: 140px;
}
#svg-3 {
    top: 160px;
    left: 250px;
}
```

The clipping path is defined in svg#svg-defs, and can be set to whatever you like.

Image attributes are visible to / accessible by js and css.
You can apply the clipping path to any html element with css of

```
myElement {
    clip-path: url(#clip-triangle);
}
```

but this is only reliable on firefox so far as I can tell.

Note: solution only tested on FF and chrome

note: small edit to move `:hover` from the svg to the embedded image, to correct problem with hover triggered outside clip area

Comment: This is for sure a good solution! For browser comptability i will use a fallback. Thx!

Comment: np. the main method I outlined should be good on all the new browsers. It's the snippet at the end, which is cleaner and nicer, that only works on FF

Comment: glanced at it again and noticed a logic error with the hover. fixed. http://jsfiddle.net/xTd6Y/4/